# How to store images into ORMLite

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I've an application that each member has a profile photo. The user can select an image from gallery. I'm going to store the users profile image into ORMLite database.

```
     profileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(i, 999);
                }
            });

  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 999 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            try {
                photo = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                profileImage.setImageBitmap(photo);
                user.setMember_picture(imageToByte(photo));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private byte[] imageToByte(Bitmap b){
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputstream);
        return outputstream.toByteArray();
    }
```

In Uer class :

```
  @DatabaseField(columnName = "PICTURE", dataType = DataType.BYTE_ARRAY)
    private byte[] member_picture;
```

but it does not work!

Answer (score 1):

You can store your image as a string in your database. To do that you have to use `Base64` class, for example:

```
private String imageToString(Bitmap b){
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputstream);
    return Base64.encodeToString(outputstream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);         
}
```

But do not forget to update `DataType` in your `@DatabaseField`.

Answer (score 0):

Storing images (or any kind of files for that matter) in a database is generally a sub-optimal solution as accessing them can be very expensive and slow from an IO perspective. That problem can be compounded when your users are choosing especially large images.

A good and commonly used practice is to save a copy of the image file and then to store the path to that file in the database.